# Confused: Notation - Definition of Logical Relations

Tags: logic

I have given: $\neg (\neg X) = X$

However then my lecturer showed us: $ (¬(¬B) ∨ ¬A) \Leftrightarrow (B ∨ ¬A) $

Is therefore the equality sign incorrect in? $ (¬(¬B) ∨ ¬A) =(B ∨ ¬A) $

This makes me not fully understand the details, when to use equality and equivalence sign regarding = and <=> .

I often see in literature: $\neg (\neg X) = X$

However $\neg (\neg X) \Leftrightarrow X$ seems to express the relations between two statements better. I find this confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it appears that $=$ and $\iff$ are expressing the same thing.  This may be due to the fact that if $A\iff B$, and $F$ is a formula with $A$, then $F$ is logically equivalent to the formula obtained by replacing every instance of $A$ in $F$ with $B$.

Comment: I find this use of "=" and "<=>" quite questionable. I am also not sure what to think about "F is a formula with A" (Example?) .
In the lecture notformulas etc. were introduced, just that A,B, X represent statements.

Comment: Sorry, by formula I mean statement.  For example, if $A\iff B$, and $F=(A\vee C)\implies A$, then $F$ is logically equivalent to $(B\vee C)\implies B$.